# -bash: source: filename argument required

Tags: python, bash

I'm working through a Python tutorial, and I attempted to pip install autoenv==1.0.0. I created the .env file in the dir

```
source env/bin/activate
export APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"
```

and then ran these commands in the shell, outside of  a venv

```
echo "source `which activate.sh`" >> ~/.bashrc
 source ~/.bashrc
```

I got back:

```
-bash: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
```

Come to find out, autoenv failed to install. I was able to get it to install and re-ran the above commands and now it works but I'm still getting the above message whenever I reload the terminal

How can I find and remove the source command or resolve it?

** edit: running which activate returns

```
23:24 $ which activate.sh
/usr/local/bin/activate.sh
```

I've looked in .bash_profile and can't find anything that seems related.
I've looked in the .bashrc file and found a path to activate.sh, though the path has the file located in the bin which it is not.

Comment: Add output of `which activate.sh` to your question.

Comment: `which activate.sh` would return only if `activate.sh` is in your `PATH`. Otherwise it returns a null. So just as cyrus said, you need to show output of `which activate.sh`.

Comment: $ which activate.sh
/usr/local/bin/activate.sh

Comment: Add output of `grep source ~/.bashrc` to your question.

Comment: Ok. So I found the issue, there were 3 random "source" commands mixed in with, for some reason, ~100  HEROKU_AC_BASH_SETUP_PATH=/Users/michaelalbonetti/Library/Caches/heroku/autocomplete/bash_setup && test -f $HEROKU_AC_BASH_SETUP_PATH && source $HEROKU_AC_BASH_SETUP_PATH;  statements. the /usr/local/bin/activate.sh is in there as well. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

After running

```
grep source ~/.bash
```

suggested by Cyrus above, I found 3 random "Source" commands, after deleting them, the issue went away.

Thanks, Cyrus and Mihir for your help.